# Optimized methods to compare and evaluate the largest count among 5 different count variables in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to see if there is a efficient method to compare counts like (Acount, BCount, CCount,DCount, ECount) and evaluate the which count is largest in JAVA?

The program can use recursion but I wanted to know any optimized method to achieve this.

Comment: would you explain what `count` variable is?

Comment: I am sorry if I got your question right. As I mentioned I have different counts and all are integers.

Comment: Well, you could put them in an array and use a `for` loop with something like `if (counts[i] > max) { max = counts[i]; }`. Or just use `IntStream.of(a, b, c, d, e).sum()`.

Comment: I don't understand things like 'Acount', 'Bcount' or else. You mean that there are several int values and wanna get biggest int value? If it is, optimization is not necessary.

Comment: This *smells* like a premature optimization.  But the most efficient will be something like this: `int max = acount; if (bcount > max) { max = bcount; } if (ccount > max) { max = ccount; }` and so on.  But the saving you are making will probably be so small that **it is not worth the effort to optimize this**.

Comment: * Of course, I mean `max()` instead of `sum()`.

Comment: Which inefficient_method did you try?

Comment: @AlexRudenko: I have tried the below 2 methods 1. Using Recursion 2. Using plain loops for comparing and updating the max value. I  needed this groups help to find the best optimized method.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, it is up to whichever you find easier to read.
You could firstly use an IntStream:

```
int max = IntStream.of(ACount, BCount, CCount, DCount, ECount).max().getAsInt();
```

or, you could use an array of integers either manually going through each value:

```
int[] list = {ACount, BCount, CCount, DCount, ECount};
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i : list) {
    if (i > max) max = i;
}
```

or sorting the list and grabbing the largest value. This might be better if you have to access the smallest value as well.

```
int[] list = {ACount, BCount, CCount, DCount, ECount};
Arrays.sort(list);
int max = list[list.length - 1];
```

or, you could just use nested math max methods:

```
int max = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(ACount, BCount), CCount), Math.max(DCount, ECount));
```

However, it is important to note that computers are fast enough to not need every small optimization. Something as small as comparing 5 int values will not take long no matter how you do it, so it is generally better to make your code more readable rather than more efficient in these situations, as often the minuscule gain is not worth the decrease in readability.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare n values, so I don't think it's possible to do this better than O(n).

The "efficiency" depends on your use case. If you only have 5 values, and you only need to do it once, then I'd argue that starting up a stream is probably not going to be the best approach. Though it may not be very important, since the loss of a few milliseconds just once is usually not a big deal. But if you get the JVM to JIT (Just In Time Compilation) with running it for a billion values, then checking out the different runtimes is my preferred way to figure out the most "effective" way.

In the below you can run it with different values for how many `ints` are in the array and how many times you'd like to run your max function. As I mentioned, I've found that streams are not very efficient when I only have 5 values.

You should probably not be running the test on a workstation, since those have lots of other stuff they need to do. I've found my own to be very unpredictable when trying to time things, though it seems to consistently give me the best output for the `justLoop` method.

```
C:\..snip..>java Testing.java
Ternary    : 23561
JustLoop   : 12663
MathMax    : 35049
Stream     : 46596
```

The code just has 4 different ways of getting the max:

- Using a ternary, that will write to the max on every loop
- A regular for loop and an if-statement
- Using `Math.max()` instead of the if-statement.
- Using `IntStream` and its `max()` function.

It starts by creating an array of ints. Then it calls a timer function passing in one of the 4 different methods:

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Testing {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int repeat = 10000;
    int arraySize = 10000;
    int[] countsRandom = randomCounts(arraySize);
    printIt("Ternary",  timeIt(() -> regularLoopTernary(countsRandom), repeat));
    printIt("JustLoop", timeIt(() -> justLoop(countsRandom), repeat));
    printIt("MathMax",  timeIt(() -> justLoopWithMathMax(countsRandom), repeat));
    printIt("Stream",   timeIt(() -> stream(countsRandom), repeat));
  }
  
  public static int regularLoopTernary(int[] counts) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : counts) {
      max = i > max ? i : max;
    }
    return max;
  }

  public static int justLoop(int[] counts) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : counts) {
      if (i > max) {
        max = i;
      }
    }
    return max;
  }

  public static int justLoopWithMathMax(int[] counts) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : counts) {
      max = Math.max(max, i);
    }
    return max;
  }

  public static int stream(int[] counts) {
    return IntStream.of(counts)
                    .max()
                    .orElseThrow();
  }

  // get some ints
  public static int[] randomCounts(int amount) {
    return IntStream.range(0, amount)
                    .map(i -> (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                    .toArray();
  }

  // get the averge time only
  public static long timeIt(Runnable runMe, int times) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      runMe.run();
    }
    return (System.nanoTime() - start) / times;
  }

  public static void printIt(String title, long averagetime) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s : %d%n", title, averagetime);
  }
}
```